# How to extract SFX files in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am attempting to extract the Microsoft Virtual Box Image for Windows8.1 / IE11

The host system is Ubuntu ...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I downloaded 4 files, part1 is an SFX file, parts 2,3 and 4 are RAR files.

After running `chmod 777` on all files, I tried to extract the archive using `./filename.sfx` but this failed with the error:

```
daniel@daniel-son:~/Desktop/vBoxImages/Win$ ./IE11.Win8.1.For.LinuxVirtualBox.part1.sfx 
./IE11.Win8.1.For.LinuxVirtualBox.part1.sfx: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

I've tried to use unzipsfx but I get ...

```
daniel@daniel-son:~/Desktop/vBoxImages/Win$ unzipsfx IE11.Win8.1.For.LinuxVirtualBox.part1.sfx 
UnZipSFX 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP (http://www.info-zip.org).
unzipsfx:  cannot find myself! [unzipsfx]
daniel@daniel-son:~/Desktop/vBoxImages/Win$
```

unrar commands says SFX is not a rar archive.

If I try and unrar part 2 it says:

> WARNING: You need to start extraction from a previous volume to unpack
> IE11 - Win8.1.ova

The 4 files are the only files located in the directory I am working in

How can I extract these on Ubuntu?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I found the problem - The Win 8 download was buggy - I downloaded the Win 7 files with IE 11 and did "./filename" - didn't work first time though - I read elsewhere it only works on 32 bit linux, so I installed a 32 bit linux virtual box and ran the command on that and it did the job

Comment: Just rename the .sfx to .rar, then ask file-roller to extract the part1 file. It will automatically extract the following parts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> after running chmod 777 on all files, I tried to extract the archive using ./filename.sfx but this failed with the error ...
>
> daniel@daniel-son:~/Desktop/vBoxImages/Win$ ./IE11.Win8.1.For.LinuxVirtualBox.part1.sfx
> ```
>
> ./IE11.Win8.1.For.LinuxVirtualBox.part1.sfx: line 2: syntax error near
>   unexpected token `)'

Lacking other instructions at the start of the file, the shell will try to execute its contents as if it were a list of shell commands.

I sincerely doubt that you will be able to 'self-extract' it under Linux, if the archive was created on Windows (or another operating system).

I suspect all are part of the same RAR file, where the .SFX file is the first part, and if executed will fetch the remaining parts. The segmentation is done to keep the size acceptable (and was a must when there were strict limits on e-mail servers).

> part1 is an SFX file, parts 2,3 and 4 are RAR files.

They are all parts of the same, big RAR file. You have to start on the first (.sfx) file, the rest should continue automatically (they have to be in the same directory).

Does the unrar command return immediately, or does it take some seconds? In the latter case the file could be password protected.

And finally, it's possible that the file was created with a newer version of RAR than your unrar is able to decompress.

Corollary: Never user RAR to compress archives on Linux. And, by the way, the .OVA files are *already* compressed.

Comment: *I sincerely doubt that you will be able to 'self-extract' it under Linux, if the archive was created on Windows (or another operating system).*  Not a problem, actually. You can create SFX archive targeted for platformX on another plaform, platformY. See https://netbeansscribbles.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/creating-a-self-extracting-7zip-archive-multi-platform/.